# Docker-compose EMQX bridge (MQTT bridging) setup

Tags: docker-compose, mqtt, bridge, broker, emq

I am trying to create an EMQ X bridge setup (MQTT bridging) using only docker-compose. As a reference i am looking at the [official docs](https://docs.emqx.io/en/broker/v4.3/advanced/bridge.html#mqtt-bridging-example). The use case i have in my mind is bridging [EMQ X Edge](https://docs.emqx.io/en/edge/latest/) (`emqx-edge`) to EMQ X (`emqx`), and then when a message is published to `emqx-edge` it will be forwarded to `emqx`. So far, i have created the two brokers and a network, so they can communicate(poc-bridge).

The problem is : when a message is published to a topic(e.g `sensor1/#`) to `emqx-edge` broker, it never arrived to `emqx` broker. I can not figure what is going wrong..

Bellow is the docker-compose i have so far.

```yaml
version: '3.3'
    
networks:
  poc-bridge:
    external: true

services:
  mqtt-edge:
    image: emqx/emqx-edge:latest
    container_name: edge-broker
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EMQX_LOADED_PLUGINS= "emqx_bridge_mqtt"
      - EMQX_ADMIN_PASSWORD=brokerpw1
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__ADDRESS=172.26.0.2:1883 #ip:port of mqtt-cloud
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__PROTO_VER=mqttv3        
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__BRIDGE_MODE=true          
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__CLEAN_START=true         
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__USERNAME=user          
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__PASSWORD=passw                                                       
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__CLIENTID=bridge_aws
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__KEEPALIVE=10s                 
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__FORWARDS=sensor1/#
    networks:
      - poc-bridge   
    ports:
      - 18083:18083
      - 1883:1883
      - 8883:8883
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-cloud
      
  mqtt-cloud:
    image: emqx/emqx:latest
    container_name: cloud-broker
    restart: always
    networks:
      - poc-bridge
    ports:
      - 51883:1883
      - 58883:8883
      - 58083:8083
```

Comment: What does `mqtt-edge` log? Its probably telling you what is wrong - see the [docs](https://docs.emqx.io/en/broker/v4.3/configuration/configuration.html#log-to)  for info on log levels etc - while you can access the default log file logging to `console` may be simpler.

Comment: Hi, and thank you for all your help... Using the command : docker logs --follow edge-broker , i see no error (EMQ X Edge 4.3.5 is running now!).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I was missing some more configurations... Bellow is the docker-compose yaml for bridging emqx-edge to emqx.

```
version: '3.3'

networks:
  poc-bridge:
    external: true


services:
  mqtt-edge:
    image: emqx/emqx-edge:latest
    container_name: edge-broker
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EMQX_LOADED_PLUGINS="emqx_bridge_mqtt,emqx_recon,emqx_retainer,emqx_management,emqx_dashboard"
      - EMQX_ADMIN_PASSWORD=brokerpw1
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__START_TYPE=auto
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__ADDRESS=172.26.0.2:1883 # docker-ip:port of mqtt-cloud                    
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__PROTO_VER=mqttv3     
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__BRIDGE_MODE=true        
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__CLEAN_START=true           
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__USERNAME=user         
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__PASSWORD=passw                                                       
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__CLIENTID=bridge_aws
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__KEEPALIVE=60s
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__FORWARD_MOUNTPOINT=bridge/aws/test/                                             
      - EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__FORWARDS=atlas/#
      #- EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__SUBSCRIPTION__1__TOPIC=atlas/#                          
      #- EMQX_BRIDGE__MQTT__AWS__SUBSCRIPTION__1__QOS=1                                                                                            
    networks:
      - poc-bridge   
    ports:
      - 18083:18083
      - 1883:1883
      - 8883:8883
      - 8083:8083
    depends_on:
      - mqtt-cloud
      
  mqtt-cloud:
    image: emqx/emqx:latest
    container_name: cloud-broker
    restart: always
    environment:
      - EMQX_LOADED_PLUGINS= "emqx_bridge_mqtt"
    networks:
      - poc-bridge
    ports:
      - 51883:1883
      - 58883:8883
      - 58083:8083
```